# Regex to find a movie name

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to come up with REGEX which would group a video file name so I could extract only a name and then use it to parse some web and such.

Name of a movie is almost (well, that could be a problem I guess, because it might not be always) first in the name and then there are some random letters, numbers and such.

For example:

```
Batman.v.Superman.Dawn.of.Justice.2016.BLABLABLA-XDAWEFFF
```

so its grouped like

```
(Batman.v.Superman.Dawn.of.Justice)(rest of the file)
```

and then I can just extract first group, replace dots with spaces and I'm good to go.

Another example:

```
Eye.in.the.Sky.2015.1080p.BluRay
```

into:

```
(Eye.in.the.Sky)(rest)
```

Do you guys have any regex in mind? I have no clue how to seperate them as there might be any words, numbers and such later in the name.

Comment: Movie titles have no standard. E.g what would be the expected behavior with the movie `2012`? Would the string be `2012.2009.BLABLABLA-XDAWEFFF`? If you just want to stop at the first 4 number occurrence that wouldn't be too hard but also accuracy drops there..

Comment: Maybe just split this `(Eye.in.the.Sky)` by `.`?. You should get all parts in array.

Comment: @chris85 Well see. Maybe a regex to find at the start of the second dot a year in 20xx format will works most of the time.

Comment: @chris85 Well, there are not that many cases when movie names are just numbers, so I could live with that. Could you help me with that regex which stops at the first 4 number occurence? I'm kinda new to regex and having a bit of a problem.

Comment: That could be `(.+?)\d{4}`. Capture group one would be your "title" (possibly `[0-9]` in place of `\d` if java doesnt support that).. or explode/split on periods and iterate over the return until you have a 4 digit field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best guess would be something of the sort

```
([ .\w']+?)(\W\d{4}\W?.*)
```

But as mentionned in the comments, since movie titles have no standard, and your naming convention doesn't either, this wouldn't always work.

So here's what it does, step by step:

`([ .\w']+?)`

- `[ .\w']` Any characters like *space*, *dot*, a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _ and '
- `+?` Capture has many character as necessary, until the second part of the expression

`(\W\d{4}\W.*)`

- `\W` anything that isn't a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _
- `\d{4}` four numbers 0-9
- `\W` anything that isn't a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _
- `.*` anything until the end of the string

[Here's an example](https://regex101.com/r/NTTsFD/1)

Comment: Could you tell me how can I add spaces in the first group? So it matches for example: Black Mass 2015 1080p ? I tried to add \s to the first group but it didn't work out very well...

Comment: This way: `([ \.\w']+?)`, but if you mean to replace the delimiter from a . to a space, that won't work. The expression was built expecting `.` as a delimiter. This would be a version with a space... `([\s\w']+?)(\s[0-9]{4}\s.*)` instead of a .

Comment: Just tried it on regex101 and doesnt work. It doesnt group that name at all with that blank space. Could you check it yourself?

Comment: Note `.` doesn't need to be escaped in a character class.

Comment: @chris85 
I think I just found the right one: ([ \.\w']+?)(\W?[0-9]{4}\.?.*) . Used \W so the date can be surrounded by (, , or even a space.

Comment: @doublemc what is that regex doing? Did you try my commented regex?

Answer (score 0):

If your String doesn't have any specified form which could be defined via Regex it is impossible to do that.

The problem with movies is that their names can contain anything.

To solve your problem you could use some delimiters to determine where is the end of the name when saving:

```
Batman.v.Superman.Dawn.of.Justice|2016.BLABLABLA-XDAWEFFF
```

Then you can use for example:

```
String[] s = "Batman.v.Superman.Dawn.of.Justice|2016.BLABLABLA-XDAWEFFF".split("|");
```